# QWebView не срабатывает клик по кнопкам соцсетей

Tags: qt

В QWebView загружаю сайт http://mytestcx.clan.su/, жму по кнопкам авторизации соц сетей и ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На этом сайте при щелчке на иконки соцсетей при помощи javascript создаётся новое окно, что по умолчанию в QtWebKit блокируется. Установите атрибут `JavascriptCanOpenWindows` для `QWebSettings` перед загрузкой страниц сайта:

```
QWebSettings::globalSettings()
    ->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptCanOpenWindows, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

А там не всплывающие окна должны открываться случайно? Если да, то, возможно, в QWebView они по умолчанию отключены, нужно включить.